# Why the HttpSecurity API in Spring Security is designed as is?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

In a Spring Boot project with Spring Security, I can configure the HTTP filter with the code below, where the `/about` endpoint is publicly accessible and the `/myAccount` endpoint requires authentication.

```
@Configuration
public class ProjectSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/myAccount").authenticated()
                .requestMatchers("/about").permitAll()
                .and().formLogin()
                .and().httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

The chaining looks weird to me, especially the `and` method. My preferred API is something like:

```
@Configuration
public class ProjectSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requireAuthentication(new RequestMatcher("/myAccount");
        http.permitAll(new RequestMatcher("/about");
        
        http.accept("FormLogin", "HttpBasic");

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Why is the API designed as is?

Comment: The DSL that uses `.and()` was written before Java 8 introduced lambdas. Spring Security has had a lambda DSL for a few years, you can read about it [here](https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/21/spring-security-lambda-dsl) and see examples in the Spring Security [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/index.html)

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana I read the blog post about lambda DSL. It doesn't use the `and` method. But I still don't understand why the configuration is written in the form of chained method calls, instead of what I suggest in my question.